# PDF created from Google Doc template via Apps Script has old values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Basically here is what is happening. A user submits a Google Form (later this will cause a trigger to set this off), the user then gets emailed a receipt from a template. The problem I am currently having is the copied template will update the values, but **the pdf does not have the updated valued**.

Sorry for the mess, plan on creating arrays and such later.

```
// to do : refactor or w/e 
// make it so it emails the person a pdf of the doc
var docTemplateId = 'templateID';
var headerPosition = 'A1:E1';
var dataRange = 'A2:E2'; // 
var sheetId = 'dataSoureID';
var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(sheetId, headerPosition);
var rowData = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(sheetId, dataRange);

var email = rowData.values[0][0];
var name = rowData.values[0][1];
var grade = rowData.values[0][2];
var subject = rowData.values[0][3];
var initalMeeting = rowData.values[0][4];
var techCurrentlyUsed = rowData.values[0][5];
var documentName = 'Good Teacher Planning '+ name;
var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplateId).makeCopy().getId();
DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(documentName);
var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();

// to do write get email function
function writeToTemplate() 
{ 
    body.replaceText('##email##', email);
    body.replaceText('##name##', name);
    body.replaceText('##grade##', grade);
    body.replaceText('##subject##', subject);
    body.replaceText('##initalMeeting##', initalMeeting); 
    body.replaceText('##techCurrentlyUsed##', techCurrentlyUsed);
}

function emailPDF()
{
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
  var blob = file.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(documentName);
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'hello', 'world', {attachments: blob});
  Logger.log('end email')
}

function main()
{
  writeToTemplate();
  emailPDF();
}
```

Edit: fixed with `saveAndClose();`

Comment: If you manually open the new Doc file from your Drive, is the updated content in the file?  Does your `writeToTemplate()` function work if you just ran that by itself.  You'd need modify `writeToTemplate()` function in order to test it as a stand alone function, and provide a document and body to the code.

Comment: Yes the writeToTemplate does the find and replace in the document. I've even tried doing a if statement to look for '##' before I email the pdf but it says its not there. A sleep statement does not help either

Comment: If you've solved the issue, either post your solution as an answer if you think it is useful, or delete the question

Answer (score 0):

Your blob source advanced parameter must be an array of attachments:

```
attachments: [blob1,blob2,blob3]
```

Even if you only have one attachment, you still need to use an array

```
attachments: [blob]
```